# MethodSecurityInterceptor for multiple methods

Tags: java, spring-security

I would like to secure my services layer using Spring Security. As explained in the documentation, I need to use a `MethodSecurityInterceptor` that will check if the method invocation is allowed.

To decide if a service method invocation is allowed for a given user, affecting a required role to the invoked method (using `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`) is not enough for me since it also depends on the parameters passed to the method. As suggested in the documentation, I can write a custom `AccessDecisionVoter` and access the arguments though the secured object (`MethodInvocation` in this case).

But, my authorization logic is different across the methods. For example, the arguments may be different between multiple methods and the authorization logic will also be different.

I see two options:

- I can use conditional logic in the `AccessDecisionVoter` to determine the invoked method and the authorization logic to use, but it seems to be an ugly solution.
- I can define one `MethodSecurityInterceptor` per method to secure. According to the Spring documentation, a `MethodSecurityInterceptor` is used to secure many methods, so it makes me thinking there is another way.

The same question exists for access decision after method invocation (using `AfterInvocationProvider`).

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own method security annotations based on Spring `@PreAuthorize("")` construction.

To fetch extra information about the method(beyond method argument values) to SpEL evaluation context you can implement your own MethodSecurityExpressionHandler

```
@Service
public class MySecurityExpressionHandler extends
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Override
    public StandardEvaluationContext createEvaluationContextInternal(
        Authentication auth, MethodInvocation mi) {

    StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext = super
            .createEvaluationContextInternal(auth, mi);

    SomeMethodInfoData methodInfoData = mi.getMethod(). ...;

    evaluationContext.setVariable("someData", <value computed based on method info data>);
    }

    return evaluationContext;
}
```

and register it in your `global-method-security` declaration

```
<security:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler
            ref="mySecurityExpressionHandler" />
    </security:global-method-security>
```

Now you can create custom security annotations(and extra process annotation data in MySecurityExpressionHandler if required)

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("#<someData>")
public @interface CustomSecurityAnnotation { ... }
```

for example you can create a custom annotation to check user roles without messing with strings:

```
@MyUserRoleCheck(MyAppRole.Admin)
public void someMethod()
```

Answer (score 4):

I achieved that by implementing my own `AccessDecisionManager` that delegates access decisions to my special interface `AccessDecisionStrategy`:

```
public interface AccessDecisionStrategy {

    void decide(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation methodInvocation, ConfigAttribute configAttribute);

}
```

Each access decision strategy represents different way of making access decision.

You can easily implement your own strategy (even in other language - for instance Scala):

```
public class SomeStrategy implements AccessDecisionStrategy { ...
```

As you can see, my `AccessDecisionManager` has a map of strategies. Strategy used by manager is based on annotation argument.

```
public class MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    private Map<String, AccessDecisionStrategy> strategyMap;

    public MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager(Map<String, AccessDecisionStrategy> strategyMap) {
        this.strategyMap = strategyMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
        ConfigAttribute configAttribute = getSingleConfigAttribute(configAttributes);
        AccessDecisionStrategy accessDecisionStrategy = strategyMap.get(configAttribute.getAttribute());
        if (accessDecisionStrategy == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AccessDecisionStrategy with name "
                    + configAttribute.getAttribute() + " was not found!");
        }
        try {
            accessDecisionStrategy.decide(authentication, (MethodInvocation) object, configAttribute);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private ConfigAttribute getSingleConfigAttribute(Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) {
        if (configAttributes == null || configAttributes.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid config attribute configuration");
        }
        return configAttributes.iterator().next();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(MethodInvocation.class);
    }
}
```

Now when I want to protect my method I put `@Secured` annotation with argument that is name of the strategy:

```
@Secured("GetByOwner")
FlightSpotting getFlightSpotting(Long id);
```

You can implement and configure as many strategies as you want:

```
<bean id="methodSecurityAccessDecisionManager"
      class="some.package.MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager">

    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="GetByOwner">
                <bean class="some.package.GetByOwnerStrategy"/>
            </entry>

            <entry key="SomeOther">
                <bean class="some.package.SomeOtherStrategy"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

To inject that access decision manager you type:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                            access-decision-manager-ref="methodSecurityAccessDecisionManager">
</sec:global-method-security>
```

I also implemented helper class to handle `MethodInvocation` arguments:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class MethodInvocationExtractor<ArgumentType> {

    private MethodInvocation methodInvocation;

    public MethodInvocationExtractor(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
        this.methodInvocation = methodInvocation;
    }

    public ArgumentType getArg(int num) {
        try {
            Object[] arguments = methodInvocation.getArguments();
            return (ArgumentType) arguments[num];
        } catch (ClassCastException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

}
```

Now you can easily extract interesting arguments in the code of your strategy to make decision:

Let's say I want to get argument number `0` that is of type `Long`:

```
MethodInvocationExtractor<Long> extractor = new MethodInvocationExtractor<>(methodInvocation);
Long id = extractor.getArg(0);
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer to cast Object to MethodInvocation in decide().  The Spring docs is missing that vital piece of info...

Comment: In case someone needs it, I added how to implement this using Java Config (my project uses Spring-Boot) [in this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24983046/2796922). See my answer.

Comment: For many use cases there is no need to implement your own decisionmanager. Instead you can just write a method an call it from `@Preauthorize` directly, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39972346/1169324