# How to implement annotation based security using Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-el

I'm new to Spring AOP (and AOP in general), need to implement the following:

```
@HasPermission(operation=SecurityOperation.ACTIVITY_EDIT, object="#act")
public Activity updateActivity(Activity act)
{
   ...
}
```

@HasPermission is my custom annotation, which will be used to mark all methods requiring pre-authorization. I'm using my custom implementation of security checks based on Apache Shiro. Generally, I guess that I will need to define pointcut which matches all annotated methods and also provide implementation of the aspect (either before or around).

Questions I have are re. aspect implementation.

- How do I extract *operation* and *object* parameters from the annotation?
- How can I resolve SpEL expression in object definition and get object passed as 'act' parameter?

Comment: I'm searching for the same topic. I hoped Spring had proper AOP/security annotations instead of using custom annotations. It looks like I found a tutorial that might be adapted to your case http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-aop-security

Comment: Please check my answer - it allows to get method info information to process custom annotations http://stackoverflow.com/a/13420500/241986

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer but after we were migrating some JavaEE project to Spring we made some basic security model based on *AspectJ*:

Firstly we annotate our service methods with custom **@OperationAuthorization** :

```
@OperationAuthorization
public ListOfUserGroupsTo getUserGroupsByClientId(Integer clientId) throws GenericException {
    return userGroupRepository.getAllUserGroupsForClient(clientId);
}
```

Then we have a class with **@Aspect** & **@Component** annotations which intercepts methods with specific annotations:

```
@Aspect 
@Component
public class AuthorizationAspect {

@Autowired
AuthorizationService authorizationService;

@Before(value = "@annotation(ch.avelon.alcedo.authorization.annotations.OperationAuthorization)")
public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();

    authorizationService.checkOperationAuthorization(method, args);
}
```

In ***AuthorizationService*** a method with all arguments are passed. Check whether the client is authorized to get user groups. If it's not: throw our Exception and method stops.

Comment: I have faced with the same issue - how to give access to rest api method for only authorized users by using AOP - in other words how to use aspects not only for logging but for security purposes also. SO if you throw an exception in your aspect then you prevent access but your system will not return meaningful http status.