# Data are not diplayed from postgres in java spring microservice

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Im trying to connect postgres with a spring boot microservice app.

Have make the configuration at `application.properties`

```
# spring.application.name=item-all-service
server.port = 8081
```

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = public
    spring.datasource.username=xxx
    spring.datasource.password=xx
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

```
    package com.example.itemsallservice.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "T_Item")
    public class ItemsModel implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public long itemId;

        @Column(name = "nameId")
        private String nameId;

        public ItemsModel(long i, String nameId) {
            super();
            this.itemId = i;
            this.nameId = nameId;
        }

        public ItemsModel() {}

        public long getItemId() {
            return itemId;
        }
        public void setItemId(long itemId) {
            this.itemId = itemId;
        }
        public String getNameId() {
            return nameId;
        }
        public void setNameId(String nameId) {
            this.nameId = nameId;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ItemsModel [itemId= \t " + itemId + " \t nameId=" + nameId + "] \n";
        }


    }
```

The repository class

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository  extends JpaRepository<ItemsModel, Long> {
```

Resource class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/item")
public class ItemResource {

    @Autowired
    public ItemRepository itemRepo; 


       @GetMapping("/all")
        public String getAllEmployees() {
           String result = "";

        //   Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee where email = :email");

            for(ItemsModel cust: itemRepo.findAll()  ){
              result += cust.toString() + "<br>"; 
            }

            System.out.println("itemModel" + result);
            return result;
        }
```

The result is empty

```
Hibernate: select itemsmodel0_.item_id as item_id1_0_, itemsmodel0_.name_id as name_id2_0_ from public.t_item itemsmodel0_
itemModel
```

Comment: what do you have in database?

Comment: What operation do you want to perform through database ?

Comment: It connects, it executes a query, but there is just nothing in the database. The result of an empty table is, no results.

Comment: hava some data. the statement below gives data

SELECT "itemId", "nameId"
  FROM public."T_Item";

Comment: What is there in your Repository @Stefani Totokocopullo?

Comment: Only this

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository  extends JpaRepository<ItemsModel, Long> {

Comment: copy the hibernate sql into your SQL client, does it work?

Comment: Nope. 

Hibernate :
select itemsmodel0_.item_id as item_id1_0_, itemsmodel0_.name_id as name_id2_0_ from public.t_item itemsmodel0_itemModel

SQL should be :SELECT "itemId", "nameId" FROM public."T_Item";

Comment: When you do select * from T_Item; WHat data do you get in postGres ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM public."T_Item"; 

it gives me data from table

Comment: try to add spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy' is an unknown property. Did you mean 'spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy'?

Comment: If the query would contain illegal column names it would give an error. It doesn't it simply doesn't return a result, hence the table that hibernate is using doesn't contain any data. So either you are connection to a different database or the table you are querying isn't the table that hibernate is using.

Comment: The connection is like this in postgres:
localhost > Databases (classwork) > Schemas > public > Tables (T_Item)

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/classwork
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow solved.

Hibernate its saving my table, T_Item into the same db but with different name t_item, thats why connection its ok but table its empty.

More info:

Hibernate and Spring modify query Before Submitting to DB

[Hibernate and Spring modify query Before Submitting to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343047/hibernate-and-spring-modify-query-before-submitting-to-db)