# Spring boot hibernate interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to create DB log events for every DB insert but the the sessionfactory is null in my Hibernate interceptor.
What's the simplest way for getting a hibernate session in your interception when you are using spring boot.

```
public class Interceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Autowired
SessionFactory session; //this is null not in the spring scope

public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
 sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()......
```

Comment: Why not simply use Hibernate Envers for this?

Comment: Envers looks good but i'm kind of stucked with the current And i basically have to do a sql insert to a specific table when object is persisted.

Comment: Did you take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot ?

Comment: That solution seems so complex, I only want to get the current open hibernate session in the current thread. Arent there any static util that holds current session

Answer (score 0):

You can get hibernate session by injecting `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;` and then calling `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`

Comment: The @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager is null Spring don't seem to inject it.

Comment: Well, your `Interceptor` class is POJO, it is not managed by Spring container and therefore you cannot inject anything in it. You could annotate it with `@Component` which would fix injection problem, but that might cause problems down the line.

Comment: The @Component did not help so hard to get the sessionFactory from spring when you outside the IOC