# is there a way to update an entity after any update of other entities?

Tags: java, spring

I got a project in spring and I want to set a flag on a entity meaning that any other entities are modified. So on any update on these entities i have to do another update on my entity. Do you know a correct way to do this?

Comment: You should provide more details abput your project and database

Comment: Details like what?

Comment: which database are you using? how are you communicating with database?

Comment: PostgreSQL Spring JPA

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663669/hibernate-interceptor-or-listener-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa)

```
@Component
public class MyEventListener implements PreInsertEventListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AuditRepository auditRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent preInsertEvent) {
        Object entity = preInsertEvent.getEntity();
        if (Customer.class.isInstance(entity)) {
            auditRepository.save(new Audit("inserted " + entity));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this works? I don't think so. I got a similar situation, and a code like that I will get a ConcurrentModificationException exception, because you are including a new entity to save (Audit) into a list of entities that are being saved and it's being iterated when listener is called

Comment: @dchang yes I tested it at the time, [here](https://github.com/gregclinker/jpa-example) is my code.