# Spring boot SSE (Server sent events): how to send response dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I am new to SSE (Server Sent Events) . I found a way to send response using SSE in spring boot. I am able to send response for every 20 seconds. I used below code for the same.

```
public Flux<UserDto> fetchUserEvent() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).map(intr -> generateUserEvent()).flatMapIterable(x -> x);
    }

generateUserEvent() - verify if new user added in DB. If it found user data, will return the same or will return empty object (new UserDto())
```

But the problem is , this method being called for every 20 seconds .

But , My requirement is to send the empty response to client every 20 seconds and send the respone whenever new user added to DB.

How can I achieve my goal? Or I am totally wrong conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an event publisher and listener so you can send an event to the emitter when a new user is registered.

Since you're using spring-boot and probably hibernate you can see example here on how to intercept hibernate events.

[Hibernate interceptor or listener with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663669/hibernate-interceptor-or-listener-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa)

I would ***personally*** not use flux and make a scheduled method in spring to send those empty ping responses to the emitter. example of this can be found here: https://www.roytuts.com/server-sent-events-spring-push-notifications/

More info for spring events in general can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events