# How to hook all successfull inserts, updates and deletions in a spring data repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am currently trying to build hooks that get a list of all successfully commited entity changes of a repository:

```kt
@Entity data class User(@Id val id: Long, val name: String)

interface extends JpaRepository<User, Long>

@Service
class UserService(val userRepository:UserRepository){

    @Transactional
    fun someProcess(){
        val newUser = User()
        newUser.name = "newUser"
        userRepository.save(newUser)

        val userToUpdate = userRepository.findById(1).get()
        userToUpdate.name = "updatedUser"

        val userToDelete = userRepository.findById(2).get()
        userRepository.delete(userToDelete)
    }

    // TODO implement hooks 
    fun hookAllInserts(inserts :List<User>){
        // list is expected to contain newUser
    }
    
    fun hookAllUpdates(updates: List<User>) {
        // list is expected to contain the latest state of updatedUser
    }
    
    fun hookAllDeletions(deletions: List<User>){
        // list is expected to contain the deletedUser
    }
}
```

The hooks should only be triggered after a successful commit, so changes that are rolled back are not propagated.

How can I achieve this with spring data?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a general solution for all spring data repositories,
however there is a solution for when one uses spring data in conjunction with hibernate:

```
@Component
class ChangeListener(
    private val entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory,
) : PostUpdateEventListener, PostInsertEventListener, PostDeleteEventListener {

    @PostConstruct
    private fun init() {
        val sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl::class.java)
        val registry = sessionFactory.serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry::class.java)
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE).appendListener(this)
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT).appendListener(this)
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_DELETE).appendListener(this)
    }

    override fun requiresPostCommitHanding(persister: EntityPersister): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onPostUpdate(event: PostUpdateEvent) {
        // event.entity contains the latest state of the entity
    }

    override fun onPostDelete(event: PostDeleteEvent) {
        // event.entity contains the latest state of the entity
    }

    override fun onPostInsert(event: PostInsertEvent) {
        // event.entity contains the last state of the entity
    }

}
```

It is based on Hibernate EventListeners

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448865/817385).

There is also a nice [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/) on Vlad Mihalcea's blog