# (Java) Is there a way for me to send data with every change in the database via WebSocket?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, real-time-updates

I'm a beginner in programming (and Java too) and I need to implement a service that shows changes in real time, I'm trying to use WebSocket for this. I have the following action:

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 100000)
    public void sendRealTimeUpdates() {
        List<OrdemDeServico> ordemEmProducao = repository.findByStatus("Em Produção");
        List<EmProducaoDTO> dtos = ordemEmProducao.stream()
                .map(this::convertToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/ordemDeServico", dtos);
    }
```

However, instead of performing this action every 1 minute, I'd like it to perform a change in the status field of my OrdemDeServico class each time.
Here is the class update function

```
@Transactional
    public OrdemDeServicoDTO update(Long id, OrdemDeServicoDTO dto){
        try{
            OrdemDeServico entity = repository.getReferenceById(id);
            copyDtoToEntity(dto, entity);
            if(dto.getTechnicianId() != null && dto.getTechnicianId() != 0){
                Tecnico tecnico = tecnicoRepository.findById(dto.getTechnicianId())
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Tecnico não encontrado"));
                entity.setTechnician(tecnico);
            } else {
                entity.setTechnician(null);
            }
            entity = repository.save(entity);
            return new OrdemDeServicoDTO(entity);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Nenhuma Ordem de Serviço encontrada com o id: " + id);
        }
       }
```

I thought about putting an if/else directly inside the update method, but I don't know if that would be good practice:

```
@Transactional
    public OrdemDeServicoDTO update(Long id, OrdemDeServicoDTO dto){
        try{
            OrdemDeServico entity = repository.getReferenceById(id);
            copyDtoToEntity(dto, entity);
            if(dto.getTechnicianId() != null && dto.getTechnicianId() != 0){
                Tecnico tecnico = tecnicoRepository.findById(dto.getTechnicianId())
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Tecnico não encontrado"));
                entity.setTechnician(tecnico);
            } else {
                entity.setTechnician(null);
            }
            entity = repository.save(entity);


            if(entity.getStatus().equals("Em Produção")){
                EmProducaoDTO emProducaoDto = convertToDto(entity);
                messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/ordemDeServico", emProducaoDto);
            }

            return new OrdemDeServicoDTO(entity);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Nenhuma Ordem de Serviço encontrada com o id: " + id);
        }
    }
```

It may be obvious to most people, but I'm still learning, thanks guys.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883282/how-to-hook-all-successfull-inserts-updates-and-deletions-in-a-spring-data-repo) might help.

Comment: Also, could there be other apps, or even manual inserts/updates to a table?  Some DBs support triggers and can publish a message to a queue/topic.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. @AndrewS No, at first there is only crud that does these basic operations and it is exposed in the API for the frontend to consume, so the insertions and changes are only through this endpoint

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like this:
**Dto.java:**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Dto {
    private String status;
}
```

**MessagingService.java:**

```java
public class MessagingService {
    public void sendMessage(Dto dto) {
        System.out.println(
                String.format(
                        "Send message to %s, data=%s",
                        "/topic/your_topic",
                        dto
                )
        );
    }
}
```

**NotifierService.java:**

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotifierService {
    private final MessagingService messagingService;

    public void notifyIfNeeded(Dto dto) {
        if (STATUS_FOR_NOTIFY.equals(dto.getStatus())) {
            messagingService.sendMessage(dto);
        }
    }
}
```

**DtoUpdateService.java:**

```java
public class DtoUpdateService {
    @Transactional
    public Dto update(Long id, Dto dto) {
        //your logic here
        dto.setStatus(STATUSES[new Random().nextInt(STATUSES.length)]);
        return dto;
    }
}
```

**UpdaterService.java:**

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UpdaterService {
    private final DtoUpdateService dtoUpdateService;
    private final NotifierService notifierService;

    public Dto update(Long id, Dto dto) {
        Dto updated = dtoUpdateService.update(id, dto);
        notifierService.notifyIfNeeded(updated);
        return updated;
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```java
public class Answer77231555 {
    public static final String STATUS_FOR_NOTIFY = "status_for_notify";
    public static final String STATUS_NOT_FOR_NOTIFY = "any_else";
    public static final String[] STATUSES = new String[]{STATUS_FOR_NOTIFY, STATUS_NOT_FOR_NOTIFY};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dto dto = new Dto();
        DtoUpdateService dtoUpdateService = new DtoUpdateService();
        MessagingService messagingService = new MessagingService();
        NotifierService notifierService = new NotifierService(messagingService);
        UpdaterService updaterService = new UpdaterService(dtoUpdateService, notifierService);
        updaterService.update(1L, dto);
        updaterService.update(1L, dto);
        updaterService.update(1L, dto);
        updaterService.update(1L, dto);
    }
}
```