# Hibernate interceptors with spring does not intercept

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, interceptor

I'm trying to use interceptors with hibernate in order to create a log table.
The application works fine but my interceptors are never triggered when they were supposed to be triggered.
I tried the solutions of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot/25293683#25293683) on stack overflow and I did not succed in making it work.

What I did is:

- create an entity class that will be the table where the log are stored (`UserLog`)
- create another class called by the interceptor that will fill my table (dao), in this example it is called `UserLogUtil`

I tried the first solution, making my interceptor class not dependant on spring `@Autowire` by making the `UserLogUtil` a singleton manually and adding the following line to my **application.properties** : `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=LogInterceptor`.

I also tried the second solution by autowiring `UserLogUtil` however my spring configuration is in xml and although I tried to convert the beans from the above example it did not work.

This is what my interceptor looks like:

```
public class LogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

  private UserLogUtil userLogUtil = UserLogUtil.getInstance();

  public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id, Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
      throws CallbackException {
    if (entity instanceof Owner){
      userLogUtil.log(........));
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I think I missed something in the process of building my interceptor and my design could be flawed. Do you have any idea that could make my interceptor function as it should ?

Comment: "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=LogInterceptor" so your LogInterceptor is in the default package? Or you are using the full qualified name of your LogIntercepter here, right?

Comment: @JensSchauder I used the full qualified name here : `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=com.mypackage.LogInterceptor`