# Use Spring IoC to manage Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, dependency-injection, interceptor

I'm using Spring Boot v2.0.3 with Hibernate 5.2. I would like to create an Hibernate Interceptor to generate a value in one of my entity field, based on a unique number in my database, before it got saved.

I fetched some online ressources, and ended up extending the Hibernate EmptyInterceptor to just override the onSave method.

```
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private final TicketService ticketService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomInterceptor(TicketService ticketService) {
        this.ticketService = ticketService;
    }

    public boolean onSave(Object entity,
                       Serializable id,
                       Object[] state,
                       String[] propertyNames,
                       Type[] types) {

        if (entity instanceof Ticket) {
            if (((Ticket) entity).getNumTicket() == null) {
                String pharmacyId = ((Ticket) entity).getEtablishmentId();

                Long newTicketNumber = ticketService.findMaxNumTicketForEtablishment(etablishmentId);
                // ((Ticket) entity).setNumTicket((newTicketNumber != null ? newTicketNumber : 1));
                for ( int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( "numTicket".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                        state[i] = newTicketNumber;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my application.yml config file, I added the following key :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor: com.mycompany.xxx.utils.CustomInterceptor
```

When I try a Ticket saving, I can see that the method onSave is correctly called, but as the interceptor was instantiated purely by Hibernate, it's not in the Spring bean context, so I can't use the @Autowire annotation. (so my ticketService is null).

In a old subject ( [How to use Spring managed Hibernate interceptors in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot/31725844)), I see that someone tried to override the HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration vendor properties, but it's not available anymore.

I found this issue on Github : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11211 , perfectly illustrating my problem, but I couldn't successfully make it work (tried to create an HibernatePropertieCustomizer as well, but I failed to use it).

if anyone can point me out to the right direction, I would be grateful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found this issue on Github : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11211 , perfectly illustrating my problem,

I am not sure how #11211 is related at all since you are reporting a problem trying to use dependency injection in a component that is managed by Hibernate.

First thing first, you are registering a class (not a bean) to Hibernate so adding `@Component` is not a great idea as Hibernate is now responsible to instantiate your class. If you add `@Component` it looks like you expect component scanning to handle this object (while, in fact, Hibernate will process it based on the FQN you've provided in configuration).

Then, Hibernate has added a way to customize how such instantiation happens and Spring Boot auto-configures a `SpringBeanContainer` by default as of [#13717](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13717) which is available in Spring Boot `2.1.x` only. If you want to be able to use regular dependency injection, you need to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1.

Comment: In the original post of the issue, RizziCR wrote "It's possible to add the interceptor as property "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", but this is a hibernate instance and not accessible in the spring context.". That's basically what I describe as my problem in this post. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I'll have to upgrade Spring as soon as possible.