# Problem of using hibernate interceptor in springboot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, interceptor

I want to use hibernate interceptor in spring boot in order to use the `afterTransactionCompletion()` method to do something after the transaction committed.

I follow the [How to use Spring managed Hibernate interceptors in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot) to configure(I just add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=com.lc.demo.inteceptor.MyInteceptor` in `application.properties`)

The interceptor works but there is still a problem when I try to get the transaction status in the method `afterTransactionCompletion()`, it is always `NOT_ACTIVE` (I wish it could be `COMMITTED`):

```
import static org.hibernate.resource.transaction.spi.TransactionStatus.COMMITTED;

import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.resource.transaction.spi.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class MyInteceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7992825362361127331L;

    @Override
    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        //The status is always NOT_ACTIVE
        TransactionStatus status = tx.getStatus(); //
        if (tx.getStatus() == COMMITTED) {
            System.out.println("This is what I want to do");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is what I do not want");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        // The status is ACTIVE
        TransactionStatus status = tx.getStatus();
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

I try to debug it and find that before the `afterTransactionCompletion()` is called,

in `org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionProvidedImpl` which extends `AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor`, the `commit()` method call the `afterCompletion()` method which call the `resetConnection(boolean initiallyAutoCommit)` to set the transaction status `NOT_ACTIVE`:

```
    /*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
 * See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
 */
package org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.hibernate.TransactionException;
import org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.ResourceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.LogicalConnectionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.PhysicalJdbcTransaction;
import org.hibernate.resource.transaction.spi.TransactionStatus;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

/**
 * @author Steve Ebersole
 */
public abstract class AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor implements LogicalConnectionImplementor, PhysicalJdbcTransaction {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.class );

    private TransactionStatus status = TransactionStatus.NOT_ACTIVE;
    protected ResourceRegistry resourceRegistry;

    @Override
    public PhysicalJdbcTransaction getPhysicalJdbcTransaction() {
        errorIfClosed();
        return this;
    }

    protected void errorIfClosed() {
        if ( !isOpen() ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException( this.toString() + " is closed" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceRegistry getResourceRegistry() {
        return resourceRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterStatement() {
        log.trace( "LogicalConnection#afterStatement" );
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTransaction() {
        log.trace( "LogicalConnection#afterTransaction" );

        resourceRegistry.releaseResources();
    }

    // PhysicalJdbcTransaction impl ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    protected abstract Connection getConnectionForTransactionManagement();

    @Override
    public void begin() {
        try {
            if ( !doConnectionsFromProviderHaveAutoCommitDisabled() ) {
                log.trace( "Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)" );
                getConnectionForTransactionManagement().setAutoCommit( false );
                log.trace( "Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)" );
            }
            status = TransactionStatus.ACTIVE;
        }
        catch( SQLException e ) {
            throw new TransactionException( "JDBC begin transaction failed: ", e );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void commit() {
        try {
            log.trace( "Preparing to commit transaction via JDBC Connection.commit()" );
            getConnectionForTransactionManagement().commit();
            status = TransactionStatus.COMMITTED;
            log.trace( "Transaction committed via JDBC Connection.commit()" );
        }
        catch( SQLException e ) {
            status = TransactionStatus.FAILED_COMMIT;
            throw new TransactionException( "Unable to commit against JDBC Connection", e );
        }

        afterCompletion();
    }

    protected void afterCompletion() {
        // by default, nothing to do
    }

    protected void resetConnection(boolean initiallyAutoCommit) {
        try {
            if ( initiallyAutoCommit ) {
                log.trace( "re-enabling auto-commit on JDBC Connection after completion of JDBC-based transaction" );
                getConnectionForTransactionManagement().setAutoCommit( true );
                status = TransactionStatus.NOT_ACTIVE;
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            log.debug(
                    "Could not re-enable auto-commit on JDBC Connection after completion of JDBC-based transaction : " + e
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback() {
        try {
            log.trace( "Preparing to rollback transaction via JDBC Connection.rollback()" );
            getConnectionForTransactionManagement().rollback();
            status = TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK;
            log.trace( "Transaction rolled-back via JDBC Connection.rollback()" );
        }
        catch( SQLException e ) {
            status = TransactionStatus.FAILED_ROLLBACK;
            throw new TransactionException( "Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection", e );
        }

        afterCompletion();
    }

    protected static boolean determineInitialAutoCommitMode(Connection providedConnection) {
        try {
            return providedConnection.getAutoCommit();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug( "Unable to ascertain initial auto-commit state of provided connection; assuming auto-commit" );
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionStatus getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    protected boolean doConnectionsFromProviderHaveAutoCommitDisabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.
Here are my `pom.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lc</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring transactions you can leverage [`TransactionSynchronization`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html) and use `afterCommit()`

> default void afterCommit()
>
> Invoked after transaction commit. Can perform further operations right
>   after the main transaction has successfully committed.

Usage:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){
           void afterCommit(){
                //do your thing
           }
})
```

You can also explore [`TransactionSynchronizationAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html) - in a similar way you can implement you own "AfterCommitExecutor" that implements the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface and extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter and overrides the [`afterCommit()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html#afterCommit--) method.

Comment: Thank you very much， I use the TransactionSynchronization interface and get the correct transaction status

Answer (score 0):

I use the answer by hovanessyan and it works, now let me completely describe what I did here:

I was trying to migrate other people's code to springboot, the code uses hibernate with a persistence.xml and the interceptor uses threadlocal to store all the entities in a transaction, when the transaction is committed, choose one "best" entity to email user, else do nothing and clear the threadlocal, the code is :

```
    public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7992825362361127331L;

    //The MyThreadLocal used to store all the entities in a transaction, when the transaction
    //committed, the interceptor will choose the "best" entity to email user
    private static MyThreadLocal myThreadLocal;

    public static void setMyThreadLocal(MyThreadLocal mTL) {
        MyInterceptor.myThreadLocal = mTL;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        TransactionStatus status = tx.getStatus();
        if (tx.getStatus() == COMMITTED) {
            MyThreadLocal.selectTheBestEntityToEmailUser();
        } else {
            MyThreadLocal.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        TransactionStatus status = tx.getStatus();
        MyThreadLocal.beforeTransactionCompletion();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        MyThreadLocal.resourceAdded((Entity) entity);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        Diff diff = new Diff(previousState, currentState, propertyNames);
        MyThreadLocal.resourceUpdated((Entity) entity, diff);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        MyThreadLocal.resourceRemoved((Entity) entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCollectionUpdate(Object collection, Serializable key) throws CallbackException {
        if (!(collection instanceof PersistentCollection)) {
            LOGGER.e("Unsupported collection type: {}", collection.getClass());
            return;
        }
        Entity owner = (Entity) ((PersistentCollection) collection).getOwner();
        String role = ((PersistentCollection) collection).getRole();
        MyThreadLocal.collectionResourceUpdated(owner, role);
    }
}
```

But in afterTransactionCompletion() method, the transaction status is always NOT_ACTIVE, now I use the TransactionSynchronization interface just to replace the afterTransactionCompletion() method:

```
    public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor implements TransactionSynchronization {

    //the mothod of TransactionSynchronization interface
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        if (status == STATUS_COMMITTED) {
            MyThreadLocal.selectTheBestEntityToEmailUser();
        } else {
            MyThreadLocal.clear();
        }
    }

    //the old code which works not well
    @Override
    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        TransactionStatus status = tx.getStatus();
        if (tx.getStatus() == COMMITTED) {
            MyThreadLocal.selectTheBestEntityToEmailUser();
        } else {
            MyThreadLocal.clear();
        }
    }

   ...... other codes
}
```

And the new inteceptor also need to be configured global by AOP:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class InterceptorInit{
    @Autowired
    private MyInteceptor mI;

    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void registerTransactionSyncrhonization() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(mI);
    }
}
```

Now it seems that all work well, I will continue to test.

Answer (score 0):

While I suggest usage of Spring TransactionSynchronization too. In case it can't be used (or not desired to) there are two things to note:

beforeTransactionCompletion - "Called before a transaction is committed (but not before rollback)." - which means this method can be actually used to recognize if the transaction is fine right before commit or not and save it in some temporary (ideally ThreadLocal) state.

afterTransactionCompletion - in case the transaction is rollbacked, the state of the transaction is not "NOT_ACTIVE" but "MARKED_ROLLBACK" - therefore the state "NOT_ACTIVE" in combination with beforeTransactionCompletion being actually called can be used to determine the transaction was a success.