# Hibernate @Formula set parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to know if we can set the custom parameter in @Formula through the application.

```
@Formula(TAX_RATE * price)
private Integer totalPrice;
```

TAX_RATE is **NOT** a column in database, where as 'price' **is** the column in db.

How can I set the TAX_RATE value during the runtime of the query through the application?

Somebody suggested to use Hibernate Interceptor 'onPreparedStatement' method. Is there any better way ?

Comment: You can't. If it's not a database column what is the point anyway. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for the reply. It's an API where customers in different countries use this. So, the front end application gets the TAX_RATE from another application and passes it into my application. So, to dynamically adjust the totalPrice, we are trying to use it in formula.

Comment: Ok. Ask a question about the actual problem and how you might be able to solve it.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I think this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot will help you