# How to set default entity listener use java code in `spring-data-jpa`?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I can set default entity listener use `persistence.xml`.
How to set default entity listener use java code in `spring-data-jpa`?

I want to set the entity listener dynamically,  `hibernate.session_factory.interceptor`
I did not find this in the hibernate or spring-data-jpa documentation.

[hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-default-listener)

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
                 version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener
                        class="com.miya.system.listener.BackupDataListener">
                    <post-remove method-name="postRemove" />
                </entity-listener>
            </entity-listeners>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: except @EntityListeners, because did not set dynamically

Comment: Have you tried `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.interceptor`? You can make it dynamic by putting the property in a separate profile

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57629504/1092818)

Comment: `hibernate.session_factory.interceptor` is set interceptor, but I want to set listener

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the definition of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to point it to your custom `persistence.xml`. The quick and dirty way in Spring Boot would be to create a `BeanPostProcessor`:

```
@Component
public class PersistenceXmlPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
      throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean && runtimeConditionMet()) {
            ((LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) bean).setPersistenceXmlLocation(<your custom persistence.xml location>)
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

As an alternative, you could customize the entity manager factory using `BaseJpaAutoConfiguration`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication {
    ...
}

@Configuration
public class CustomHibernateJpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

    ...// copy most methods over from HibernateJpaConfiguration

    @Override
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factoryBuilder) {
        var result = super.entityManagerFactory(factoryBuilder);
        result.setPersistenceXmlLocation(...);
        return result;
    }

}
```

(an even cleaner solution could be to extend `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`, but I hope you get the general idea).