# timescaledb with spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, timescaledb

It's super simple to crank up a little service that persists to timescaledb in spring data.  But while spring data will connect and create your schema from your model, it obviously doesn't create the hypertables that wrap your tables.  What is the standard way to create your hypertables with a spring boot service using spring data?

Comment: Do you use any database migration framework, like flyway or liquibase? Probably you'll need to add a migration to call the `create_hypertable` function.

I see some [hibernate interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283767/how-to-use-spring-managed-hibernate-interceptors-in-spring-boot/25293683#25293683) can maybe help you to rebuild the raw sql.

Comment: An interceptor operates on request scope, right?  I just need something at startup that creates the hypertable after the schema has been created by spring data.  Maybe create a special repository with a post construct method?  Surely there's a common solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
@DependsOn({"readingRepository"})
public class CustomTimescaleRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void createHypertables() {
        log.info("CREATING HYPERTABLES");
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT create_hypertable('reading','timestamp')");
        query.getFirstResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work.  I could create a schema.sql to have spring data do it automatically, but then I would have to maintain BOTH the entity AND the schema.sql file for the entire development lifecycle which seems like a pain.  Any suggestions to improve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can introduce a new annotation mechanism that wraps such cases?

Comment: This does not work.  If you query the hypertables after this executes, nothing was created.  We finally threw our hands up and created them with a script in the docker file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's standard and not using Spring Data but one option to consider is using [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), db migration tool that supports Spring well.

If your service wants to add a new timescale schema you need to add SQL file on the directory that Flyway uses. Details of how to install Flyway, where to put the SQL file can be found in the link below

- Flyway installation: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/plugins/springboot
- How to execute Flyway database migrations on startup: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/plugins/springboot

And this is an example of creating a hypertable SQL (the schema that can be found in the Timescale [official docs](https://docs.timescale.com/getting-started/latest/create-hypertable/))

```sql
-- V1_1__add_stocks_real_time.sql

CREATE TABLE stocks_real_time (
  time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE PRECISION NULL,
  day_volume INT NULL
);

SELECT create_hypertable('stocks_real_time','time');

CREATE INDEX ix_symbol_time ON stocks_real_time (symbol, time DESC);
```

If you place this SQL file in the proper place and start up the Spring server, Flyway creates a hypertable automatically like the screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Arlo Guthrie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342562/19420247)'s answer cannot work, but based on that, here is a better verion. It's really Spring style by using annotation.

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TimescaleTable {
    String tableName();

    String timeColumnName();
}
```

```java
import java.util.Set;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.EntityType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TimescaleTableInitializer {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private void createHypertable(String tableName, String timeColumnName) {
        entityManager
                .createNativeQuery(String.format(
                        "SELECT create_hypertable('%s','%s', if_not_exists => TRUE);",
                        tableName,
                        timeColumnName
                ))
                .getResultList();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // get all entities
        Set<EntityType<?>> entities = entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities();

        // for each entity
        for (EntityType<?> entity : entities) {
            // get entity class
            Class<?> javaType = entity.getJavaType();

            // check of TimescaleTable annotation
            if (javaType.isAnnotationPresent(TimescaleTable.class)) {
                // get metadata from annotation
                TimescaleTable annotation = javaType.getAnnotation(TimescaleTable.class);
                String tableName = annotation.tableName();
                String timeColumnName = annotation.timeColumnName();

                // create hypertable
                createHypertable(tableName, timeColumnName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use on data entity:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import lombok.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import ***.app.config.timescaledb.TimescaleTable;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = SensorData.TABLE_NAME)
@TimescaleTable(tableName = SensorData.TABLE_NAME, timeColumnName = SensorData.TIME_COLUMN_NAME)
@IdClass(SensorData.SensorDataID.class)
public class SensorData {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "sensor_data";
    public static final String TIME_COLUMN_NAME = "time";

    @Data
    public static class SensorDataID implements Serializable {
        private Integer id;
        private LocalDateTime time;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = TIME_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime time;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String sensor;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String data;
}
```