# MethodSecurityInterceptor for multiple methods in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

This is related to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376202/methodsecurityinterceptor-for-multiple-methods) by Mickael Marrache on how to secure services using an authorization logic that can be different across the methods.

I liked better the response provided by Maciej Ziarko using [Method Security AccessDecisionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13380952/2796922)  instead of the one accepted, since it uses the same annotation `@Secured` with diferente custom arguments.

Since I'm using Spring-Boot with no XML config, took me a while to figure out how to do it.

So, here is my answer.

It just explains how to replace the xml config with the Java Config configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After my changes, I'll add the original answer "just in case".)

In order to replace the xml configuration:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                            access-decision-manager-ref="methodSecurityAccessDecisionManager">
</sec:global-method-security>
```

It happend that the annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` doesn't have a way to specify the accessDecisionManager right there. You have to extend `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and override the `AccessDecisionManager` method.

And to implement and configure as many strategies as you want the original post has

```
<bean id="methodSecurityAccessDecisionManager"
      class="some.package.MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager">

    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="GetByOwner">
                <bean class="some.package.GetByOwnerStrategy"/>
            </entry>

            <entry key="SomeOther">
                <bean class="some.package.SomeOtherStrategy"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

Both tinks can be done using Java Config like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;


@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {

        logger.debug("accessDecisionManager config...");

        Map<String, AccessDecisionStrategy> strategyMap = new HashMap<String, AccessDecisionStrategy>();

        strategyMap.put("GetByOwner", new GetByOwnerStrategy());

        return new MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager(strategyMap);
    }

}
```

And, finally, the plain and simple Web Security Config.
Note that I'm using a "RestWebSecurity..." you can name it anyway you want.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();    
        }
    }
}
```

Just for completeness, the implemented strategy has to return `AccessDeniedException` or `InsufficientAuthenticationException` when the user shouldn't proceed. Here is an example accessing parameters and all:

```
public class GetByOwnerStrategy implements AccessDecisionStrategy {
    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication,
            MethodInvocation methodInvocation, ConfigAttribute configAttribute) {

        MethodInvocationExtractor<Object> extractor = new MethodInvocationExtractor<>(methodInvocation);
        Person person = (Person) extractor.getArg(0);
        String userId = (String) extractor.getArg(1);

        String username = authentication.getName();

        if (! ((userId.equals(username)) && (person.getSomeData().equals("SOMETHING") ) && ....) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Not enough privileges");
        }
    }
}
```

**================== ORIGINAL ANSWER =======================**

I achieved that by implementing my own AccessDecisionManager that delegates access decisions to my special interface AccessDecisionStrategy:

```
public interface AccessDecisionStrategy {

    void decide(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation methodInvocation, ConfigAttribute configAttribute);

}
```

Each access decision strategy represents different way of making access decision.

You can easily implement your own strategy (even in other language - for instance Scala):

public class SomeStrategy implements AccessDecisionStrategy { ...

As you can see, my AccessDecisionManager has a map of strategies. Strategy used by manager is based on annotation argument.

```
public class MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    private Map<String, AccessDecisionStrategy> strategyMap;

    public MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager(Map<String, AccessDecisionStrategy> strategyMap) {
        this.strategyMap = strategyMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
        ConfigAttribute configAttribute = getSingleConfigAttribute(configAttributes);
        AccessDecisionStrategy accessDecisionStrategy = strategyMap.get(configAttribute.getAttribute());
        if (accessDecisionStrategy == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AccessDecisionStrategy with name "
                    + configAttribute.getAttribute() + " was not found!");
        }
        try {
            accessDecisionStrategy.decide(authentication, (MethodInvocation) object, configAttribute);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private ConfigAttribute getSingleConfigAttribute(Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) {
        if (configAttributes == null || configAttributes.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid config attribute configuration");
        }
        return configAttributes.iterator().next();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(MethodInvocation.class);
    }
}
```

Now when I want to protect my method I put @Secured annotation with argument that is name of the strategy:

```
@Secured("GetByOwner")
FlightSpotting getFlightSpotting(Long id);
```

You can implement and configure as many strategies as you want:

```
<bean id="methodSecurityAccessDecisionManager"
      class="some.package.MethodSecurityAccessDecisionManager">

    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="GetByOwner">
                <bean class="some.package.GetByOwnerStrategy"/>
            </entry>

            <entry key="SomeOther">
                <bean class="some.package.SomeOtherStrategy"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

To inject that access decision manager you type:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                            access-decision-manager-ref="methodSecurityAccessDecisionManager">
</sec:global-method-security>
```

I also implemented helper class to handle MethodInvocation arguments:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class MethodInvocationExtractor<ArgumentType> {

    private MethodInvocation methodInvocation;

    public MethodInvocationExtractor(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
        this.methodInvocation = methodInvocation;
    }

    public ArgumentType getArg(int num) {
        try {
            Object[] arguments = methodInvocation.getArguments();
            return (ArgumentType) arguments[num];
        } catch (ClassCastException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can easily extract interesting arguments in the code of your strategy to make decision:

Let's say I want to get argument number 0 that is of type Long:

```
MethodInvocationExtractor<Long> extractor = new MethodInvocationExtractor<>(methodInvocation);
Long id = extractor.getArg(0);
```

<kbd>answered Nov 14 '12 at 14:40


    Maciej Ziarko</kbd>