# @PreAuthorize and deleting by ID

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data

I am looking to provide security around the [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) method delete(Integer id) for some Object o. I want to make sure that the Object that is about to be deleted was created by the person currently deleting the object (or an admin). I have been using @PreAuthorize consistently as a way to authorize. To secure the delete(Object o) method all I had to do was

```
 @PreAuthorize("(#o.info.creator == authentication.principal.name) or (hasRole('ADMIN'))")
 @Override
 public void delete(@P("o")Object o);
```

However, for delete by ID I have been unable to find a way to check the resulting 'creator' against our principal name. My original idea was something along the lines

```
@PreAuthorize("(**some Function Getting me the Object(#id)**.info.creator== authentication.principal.name)")
@Override
public void delete(@P("id")Integer id);
```

Is there a way to get from the ID to the object before doing the authorization? Or should I be taking a different approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use custom expressions in Spring Security @PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747452/how-to-use-custom-expressions-in-spring-security-preauthorize-postauthorize-an)

Comment: any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own annotation @CanDeleteOnlyCreatorOrAdmin. Then create aspect that(if method marked with this annotation) will take object you want to remove from db by id and check, if current authenticated user is admin or creator. If not - throw 403 .

Also you can use @PostFilter, details here:
http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/prefilter-postfilter-in-spring-security