# How to pass Class to spring annotation via AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop

I'm trying to pass Class object (MyEntity) to @PreAuthorize Spring annotation.

```
@PreAuthorize("checkMethod(#id, #MyEntity.class)")
public MyEntity getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to solve it without @Bean declaration?

```
@Bean
public Class<MyEntity> myEntityClass() {
    return MyEntity.class;
}
```

Comment: Is your question related to passing of the MyEntity or how to make it work without using @Bean over the MyEntity

Comment: second one: how to make it work without using @Bean over the MyEntity

Comment: I have approximately 200 entities and don't wanna create bean for each of them

Comment: Kindly share your checkMethod code

Comment: I was using https://stackoverflow.com/a/26754125/8580230 and checkMethod signature the same as isAdmin/isOwner. Class object I need for JPA.

Comment: well isAdmin/isOwner doesnt take an argument and also I am curious to find out what exactly is the implementation when you are expecting 200 types of bean in it

Comment: well actually I'm getting #id argument inside checkMethod anyway, implementation is simple to filter restricted classes from all