# Spring security tag to check specific identity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The idea is to show in jsp file some part but only to those who have admin role or some particular person has access to it.

Suppose, I have a QA app. Person creates a question. Now, if a creator of a question or admin opens a question, they have "delete" button to delete question and none else have this button.

A person and a question have one-to-many relationship. So particular question contains particular person's id.

I can check if a person has admin role

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')"> question entity </sec:authorize>
```

But how can I check if person has the specific right, let's say, that depends on person's id which is contained in a question entity?

What if I pass in Model person's id and question's id and then check if they are equal? What tags should I use?

**Edit:**
In general, I want my own in-page authorization expression like

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')"> question entity </sec:authorize>
```

but instead of default hasRole() I'd like to have isOwner()

Comment: can you please  post more details

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747452/how-to-use-custom-expressions-in-spring-security-preauthorize-postauthorize-an)

Comment: @HadiJ it is explained there how to implement your own method level authorization(for instance, PreAuthorize,PostAuthorize) but how can I create my own in-page level like authorization(<security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the idea was to create custom web security expression to use in JSP like: `<sec:authorize access="isOwner()"> question entity </sec:authorize>` and it was explained how to do so in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361009/9843507)