# How to create custom web security expression to use in JSP?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

How is it possible to create your own web security expression, so that I'll be able to use it in JSP file like:

```
<sec:authorize access="isOwner()"> some content here </sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you need.
Follow below to create custom SpEL expression:

1) Create custom subclass of ***WebSecurityExpressionRoot*** class. In this subclass create a new method which you will use in expression. For example:

```
public class CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot extends WebSecurityExpressionRoot {

    public CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a, FilterInvocation fi) {
        super(a, fi);
    }

    public boolean yourCustomMethod() {
        boolean calculatedValue = ...;

        return calculatedValue;

    }
}
```

2) Create custom subclass of ***DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler*** class and override method ***createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi)*** (not createEvaluationContext(...)) in it to return your ***CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot*** instance. For example:

```
@Component(value="customExpressionHandler")
public class CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Override
    protected SecurityExpressionRoot createSecurityExpressionRoot(
            Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {

        WebSecurityExpressionRoot expressionRoot = new CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);

        return expressionRoot;
}}
```

3)  Define in your spring-security.xml the reference to your expression handler bean

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/error403.jsp" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    ...

    <security:expression-handler ref="customExpressionHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

After this, you can use your own custom expression instead of the standard one:

```
<security:authorize access="yourCustomMethod()">
```

Comment: How can I define the reference to my expression handler bean using Java code instead of xml?

Comment: Fine, I just autowired expression handler and did the following thing: `http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(expressionHandler),` so now it works perfectly. Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using `Shiro` framework.
Official Link:http://shiro.apache.org/ 
Implement `AuthorizingRealm` with `extends`, then add the expression of security control in the `doGetAuthorizationInfo(...)`. 
In the JSP, first add Shiro JSP tag library, official link :[http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-taglibrary](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html)

Using `<shiro:hasPermission name="...">...</shiro:hasPermission>` can control the things you need. `name` property is the expression which will compare with what you set in `AuthorizingRealm`.

Here is permission expression guide :http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html

Here is some usage:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="shiro" uri=http://shiro.apache.org/tags %>
<html>
<body>
    <shiro:hasPermission name="users:manage">
        <a href="manageUsers.jsp">
            Click here to manage users
        </a>
    </shiro:hasPermission>
    <shiro:lacksPermission name="users:manage">
        No user management for you!
    </shiro:lacksPermission>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shiro is a more effective, more configurable framework, so I will recommend it to you.